# Frames with PHP

Tags: php, html, frames

Can I use HTML Frames with PHP?

I presumed I can do this by..

```
<?php
session_start();
require("auth.php");
require("do_html_header.php");
if($_SESSION['SESS_admin'] == 0)
require("do_menu.php");
else
require("do_menu3.php");

do_html_header();
print"<h1>Welcome ". $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']."!</h1>";
do_menu();
?>
</body>

<frameset rows="50%,50%">
<frame noresize="noresize" src="limits.php" />
<frame noresize="noresize" src="limits.php" />
</frameset>

</html>
```

I have put it everywhere but it seems not to show up..

Google just confused me.

Thanks in Advance :D

Comment: Frames have nothing to do with PHP really. As long as the PHP scripts output valid HTML, everything will work fine. What you are showing above (a `body` and a `frameset` element in the same document) is not valid HTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PHP with HTML framesets, but you shouldn't be outputting anything in a `<body>` element of a frameset page (even then it should be `<noframes>`, not `<body>`). Content goes within the individual pages contained by your `<frame />` elements.

Anyway, don't use frames. PHP as a templating language is meant to help you separate components of your pages by way of [includes](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp), rendering framesets completely unnecessary in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use frames. But you'll have to output the actual content in the frameset files, in your case `limits.php`. Beware of a few things here:

- Starting the session in the frameset file is ok.
- But you'll also have to session_start() in the limits.php frame content file.
- Likewise the HTTP authentication should be performed in all frame files.
- Do not assume that people cannot access do_menu3.php directly.

I've previously used frames for implementing a NortonCommand-[clone](http://sourceforge.net/project/screenshots.php?group_id=75510&ssid=14026) for the web, where it's more senseful than CSS-arranging divs. However, handling jQuery is more cumbersome with frames. In regards to PHP it's as simple as treating every frame script as individual entry script.