# Div won't refresh in PHP using include and Javascript

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to create a login page.

For now you simply click *Login* on the login.php page, it then sends a request to *index.php* which shows a message for a successful login and changes a variable `loggedin` which is used in the session to see if user has logged in or not, then redirects to the home page.

Now my *navigation bar* (nav.php) checks the session variable `loggedin` and will display contents accordingly i.e whether a user is logged in or not and if they can see the My profile link etc...

The problem is when the login page (`login.php`) sends a request to `index.php` for the logged in page it does a check like this:

index.php:

```
.row, .col { overflow: hidden; position: absolute; }
.row { left: 0; right: 0; }

...

.menu.row { height: 75px; top: 75px; background-color: #EDEDED;  }
...

<div class="menu row">
    <?php 
        include("nav.php"); ?>
</div> 

...

case 'logged_in':
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;   
    print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    print 'alert("You have been logged in successfully and will be re-directed to your homepage...")'; 
    print '</script>';
    include('home.html');
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(".menu.row").load("index.php");</script>';
break;
```

as you can see the last echo statement attempts to update the menu row div class which contains `nav.php` in order to reflect the changes from the session variable `loggedin` being displayed but it only shows changes after I click another link on the `nav.php` page.

So basically I'm asking why does my

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(".menu.row").load("index.php");</script>';
```

doesn't refresh the div which contains my *nav.php* and thus allowing *nav.php* to execute the PHP code to check the variable `loggedin` and act accordingly?

Here is some of the code:

index.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>CC Chat</title>
        <meta 
        http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" 
        />
        <!-- 
        Thanks too http://stackoverflow.com/a/7851347/1133011 for the help
        on layout which acts more like frames but avoids them and using divs. As frames have 
        known draw backs see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600648/frames-with-php we
        should thus rather use include in php
        !-->
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        /* Generic pane rules */
        body { margin: 0 }
        .row, .col { overflow: hidden; position: absolute; }
        .row { left: 0; right: 0; }
        .col { top: 0; bottom: 0; }
        .scroll-x { overflow-x: auto; }
        .scroll-y { overflow-y: auto; }

        .header.row { height: 75px; top: 0; background-color: #E5E5E5; }
        .menu.row { height: 75px; top: 75px; background-color: #EDEDED;  }
        .body.row { top: 150px; bottom: 50px; background-color: #F5F5F5; }
        .footer.row { height: 75px; bottom: 0; background-color: #EBEBEB; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header row">
        <?php include("header.html"); ?>
        </div> 

        <div class="menu row">
        <?php 
            include("nav.php"); ?>
        </div> 

        <div class="body row scroll-y">
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
                switch ($_GET['page']) {
                    case 'login':
                        include('login.php');
                    break;
                    case 'logged_in':
                        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;   
                        print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
                        print 'alert("You have been logged in successfully and will be re-directed to your homepage...")'; 
                        print '</script>';
                        include('home.html');
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(".menu.row").load("index.php");</script>';
                    break;
                    case 'log_out':
                        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
                        include('loggedout.html');
                    break;
                    case 'profile':
                        include('profile.php');
                    break;
                    case 'contact_us':
                        include('contact.html');
                    break;
                    default:
                    include('home.html');
                    break;
                }
            } else
                include('home.html'); 
        ?>
        </div> 

        <div class="footer row">
        <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

nav.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Navigator</title>
        <meta
        http-equiv="content-type"
        content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
        />
    </head>

    <body>
            <p align="center">
                <?php 
                    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
                        switch ($_SESSION['loggedin']) {
                            case true:
                                echo "<a href=\"index.php?page=home\">Home</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=contact_us\">Contact Us</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=profile\">My profile</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=log_out\">Log out</a>";
                            break;
                            default:
                                echo "<a href=\"index.php?page=home\">Home</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=contact_us\">Contact Us</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=login\">Login</a>";
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<a href=\"index.php?page=home\">Home</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=contact_us\">Contact Us</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=login\">Login</a>";
                    }
                ?>  
            </p>
    </body>

</html>
```

login.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type"
        content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
        />
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2 align="center">Login</h2>
        <p align="center">
            <?php 
                $var=true;//user password was correct
                if($var==true){
                    echo '<a href="index.php?page=logged_in">Login</a>';
                } else {
                    print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
                    print 'alert("Password is incorrect.")'; 
                    print '</script>';
                }
            ?> 
        </p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're using jQuery in `echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(".menu.row").load("index.php");</script>';` but where is jQuery being loaded?

Comment: @j08691 Is that JQuery?? Beats me I got it from another answer on SO cant find it now to link it but thats what the OP marked as the answer for refershing a div in php  after an `include(..)`....

Comment: Yes, that's jQuery and if you're not including jQuery then it won't do a thing.

Comment: Okay but I see I have `text/javascript"` I attempted changing to `echo '<script type="text/jquery">$(".menu.row").load("index.php");</script>';` but still no effect after I press Login I still have to click a link on the nav.php for it to refresh

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library, it's not its own language.

Comment: @crimson_penguin I see sorry for my ignorance I changed it back to what is was... obviously still not working though maybe my identifier for the `div` `menu row` is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Okay but I see I have text/javascript" I attempted changing to echo cript type=text/jquery">$(".menu.row").load("index.php");; but still no effect after press Login I still have to click a link on the nav.php for it to refresh – David Kroukamp 4 mins ago

I'm afraid I can't make comments so have to use an answer. Changing the type to text/jquery won't work. Include the following before you call the jQuery....

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And leave your script type as text/javascript

You can also download the latest jquery.min.js and link to it on your own server rather than linking to googleapis.com

**UPDATE**

At the moment you are including the nav.php and THEN setting the session variable. This is why it works when you click on nav.php after the page has loaded.

```
case 'logged_in':
                        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
```

the above needs to be set before

```
include('nav.php');
```

Comment: thanks this is now half working but now somehow my footer is replacing my nav bar???? and the code is still what I posted

Comment: What happens when you change the echo to: echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(".menu.row").load("nav.php");</script>';

Comment: Nothing it just stays the same until I click the nav.php

Comment: The issue is include('nav.php') is being executed before the $_SESSION['logged_in'] variable is being set to true

Comment: How would I get around that?

Comment: +1 thank you moved my div which contains nav below my body div which has the php code to change variable and it worked thanks a million

Comment: You need to move the case when page=loggedin set $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true to before the include('nav.php'); line

Answer (score 1):

A JavaScript library is a bunch of code that someone has written to provide you with certain functionality. It's not its own separate language. So your `type` should still be `text/javascript`. But you need to include that library on your page. You can either download the it from http://jquery.com/download/ or you can use a hosted version, like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Or use Google's CDN if you prefer:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

***UPDATE:***

`nav.php` looks like it holds an entire HTML document. You're inserting that into a div in another HTML document. You should modify nav.php to just include the content that you want to go into the div (probably just the contents of the `<p>` tag.

Also, it doesn't look like you're starting your PHP session in nav.php. So it will not have access to `$_SESSION` variables. Make sure you call `session_start();` in `nav.php`.

Comment: Calling `$(".menu.row").load("index.php");` will replace the contents of the element with the classes `menu` and `row` with the contents of `index.php`. So it sounds like the contents of `index.php` is your footer, or all of your page, and only the bottom  of the div (the footer) is showing in the div. Perhaps you meant to load `nav.php` instead of `index.php`?

Comment: Hmm thank you I never knew that I now changed index.php to nav.php as thats what I want to refresh but no difference except my footer is no more rpelacing the nav.php page

Comment: It looks like there are a few problems. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in nav.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Navigator</title>
        <meta
        http-equiv="content-type"
        content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
        />
    </head>

    <body>
            <p align="center">
                <?php 
                    if(isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['page'])) {
                        if($_GET['page'] == 'logged_in') {
                            echo "<a href=\"index.php?page=home\">Home</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=contact_us\">Contact Us</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=profile\">My profile</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=log_out\">Log out</a>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<a href=\"index.php?page=home\">Home</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=contact_us\">Contact Us</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=login\">Login</a>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<a href=\"index.php?page=home\">Home</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=contact_us\">Contact Us</a> <a href=\"index.php?page=login\">Login</a>";
                    }
                ?>  
            </p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Switch statements are tricky, so I tend to stand clear of them. Your initial mistake was referencing the variable `$_SESSION['logged_in']` rather than `$_SESSION['page']`.

Comment: I have it working in my sandbox. Copy & pasted everything from your post. Edited my post to include full code.

Comment: OOh very nice its nearly working but now it lgs me in and shows Im logged in but if I click another link it goes back to as if I was not logged in... I guess thats the side effect of checking the page?